# What is the way of declaring an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm just learning JavaScript and it seems like there are a number of ways to declare arrays.

1. `var myArray = new Array()`
2. `var myArray = new Array(3)`
3. `var myArray = ["apples", "bananas", "oranges"]`
4. `var myArray = [3]`

What are their difference, and what are the preferred ways?

According to [this website](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays) the following two lines are very different:

```
var badArray = new Array(10); // creates an empty Array that's sized for 10 elements
var goodArray= [10];          // creates an Array with 10 as the first element
```

> As you can see these two lines do two very different things. If you
>   had wanted to add more than one item then badArray would be
>   initialized correctly since Javascript would then be smart enough to
>   know that you were initializing the array instead of stating how many
>   elements you wanted to add.

Is what the authors trying to say is `Array(10)` creates an array with precisely 10 elements and `[10]` creates an array of undefined size with the 0th element being 10? Or what does this mean?

Comment: #3 is the most common. You should read Crockford's "Javascript: The Good Parts" for a really solid foundation.

Comment: See also [`Array` documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/).

Comment: No @Rocket, they are not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The preferred way is to always use the literal syntax with square brackets; its behaviour is predictable for any number of items, unlike `Array`'s. What's more, `Array` is not a keyword, and although it is not a realistic situation, someone could easily overwrite it:

```
function Array() { return []; }

alert(Array(1, 2, 3)); // An empty alert box
```

However, the larger issue is that of consistency. Someone refactoring code could come across this function:

```
function fetchValue(n) {
    var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);

    return arr[n];
}
```

As it turns out, only `fetchValue(0)` is ever needed, so the programmer drops the other elements and breaks the code, because it now returns `undefined`:

```
var arr = new Array(1);
```

Answer (score 34):

In your first example, you are making a blank array, same as doing `var x = []`.  The 2nd example makes an array of size 3 (with all elements `undefined`).  The 3rd and 4th examples are the same, they both make arrays with those elements.

Be careful when using `new Array()`.

```
var x = new Array(10); // array of size 10, all elements undefined
var y = new Array(10, 5); // array of size 2: [10, 5]
```

The preferred way is using the `[]` syntax.

```
var x = []; // array of size 0
var y = [10] // array of size 1: [1]

var z = []; // array of size 0
z[2] = 12;  // z is now size 3: [undefined, undefined, 12]
```

Answer (score 12):

To declare it:

```
var myArr = ["apples", "oranges", "bananas"];
```

To use it:

```
document.write("In my shopping basket I have " + myArr[0] + ", " + myArr[1] + ", and " + myArr[2]);
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as specified at the end of the entry.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways to create arrays.

The traditional way of declaring and initializing an array looks like this:

```
var a = new Array(5); // declare an array "a", of size 5
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];  // initialize each of the array's elements to 0
```

Or...

```
// declare and initialize an array in a single statement
var a = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: IMHO this is exactly the way of how **not to do it**. Look at other answers.

Comment: The first way described above does not do what it says it does. It actually creates an array of size 5 (all elements undefined), assigning it to the variable `a`, and then immediately throws that array away and assigns to the variable `a` another, brand new array of size 5, with a zero stored at each index. To have kept the existing array and initialized its elements, what would have been needed was `var a = new Array(5);` followed by `a[0] = 0; a[1] = 0;` etc.

Comment: var a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an array whose main feature is it's length, rather than the value of each index, defining an array as `var a=Array(length);` is appropriate.

eg-

```
String.prototype.repeat= function(n){
    n= n || 1;
    return Array(n+1).join(this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can declare like this

```
const [alice, bob] = [1, 2]

console.log(alice) // 1
console.log(bob) // 2
```