# It is not printing with the 2nd largest number using Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Find the 2nd Highest and Lowest</title>
    <script>
    function findthenum() {


        var num1 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num1.value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num2.value);
        var num3 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num3.value);
        var num4 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num4.value);
        var num5 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num5.value);

        var myArray[num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];


        findsecondlargest(myArray);
    }

    function findsecondlargest(arr)
    {


    var fLargeNum = 0;
    var sLargeNum = 0;

    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(fLargeNum < arr[i]){
            sLargeNum = fLargeNum;
            fLargeNum = arr[i];         
        }else if(sLargeNum < arr[i]){
            sLargeNum = arr[i];
        }
    }

    print(sLargeNum);

}
  function print(largenum){
    document.write(largenum);
  }




    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="findthenumber">
<p>Enter number 1:<input type="number" name="num1"></p>
<p>Enter number 2:<input type="number" name="num2"></p>
<p>Enter number 3:<input type="number" name="num3"></p>
<p>Enter number 4:<input type="number" name="num4"></p>
<p>Enter number 5:<input type="number" name="num5"></p>
<button type="submit" onclick="findthenum()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing is that the user will input 5 numbers and the function will find the second largest number using array but it is not printing.

I am having a problem passing the user input to the array. I am not quite sure if I am doing the right thing doing this  "var myArray[num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]; "

Comment: It should be `var myArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];`. (I didn't bother checking your actual algorithm.)

Comment: let myArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an equals sign to assign the values to your array:

```
var myArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your array like this:

```
var myArray = [num1,num2,num3,num4,num5];
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403068/what-is-the-way-of-declaring-an-array-in-javascript-beginner) will help you understand about declaring arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
var myArray[num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];
```

you are not defining the array. To do this use an equal sign between the name and the value of the variable.

```js
    function findthenum() {


        var num1 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num1.value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num2.value);
        var num3 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num3.value);
        var num4 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num4.value);
        var num5 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num5.value);

        var myArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];


        findsecondlargest(myArray);
    }

    function findsecondlargest(arr){
       var fLargeNum = 0;
       var sLargeNum = 0;
   
       for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
           if(fLargeNum < arr[i]){
               sLargeNum = fLargeNum;
               fLargeNum = arr[i];         
           }else if(sLargeNum < arr[i]){
               sLargeNum = arr[i];
           }
       }

       print(sLargeNum);

    }
    function print(largenum){
         alert(largenum);
    }
```

```html
<body>
<form method="post" name="findthenumber">
<p>Enter number 1:<input type="number" name="num1"></p>
<p>Enter number 2:<input type="number" name="num2"></p>
<p>Enter number 3:<input type="number" name="num3"></p>
<p>Enter number 4:<input type="number" name="num4"></p>
<p>Enter number 5:<input type="number" name="num5"></p>
<button type="submit" onclick="findthenum()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

As a more general solution I added a bubble sort function to find any position of array.

```js
    function findthenum() {


        var num1 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num1.value);
        var num2 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num2.value);
        var num3 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num3.value);
        var num4 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num4.value);
        var num5 = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.num5.value);
        var pos = parseFloat(document.findthenumber.pos.value);

        var myArray = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5];


        findByIndex(myArray, pos);
    }

    function findByIndex(arr, pos){
        bubbleSort(arr);
        alert(arr[pos]);
    }

    function bubbleSort(a){
        var swapped;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
                if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                    var temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i+1];
                    a[i+1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        } while (swapped);
    }
```

```html
<body>
<form method="post" name="findthenumber">
<p>Enter number 1:<input type="number" name="num1"></p>
<p>Enter number 2:<input type="number" name="num2"></p>
<p>Enter number 3:<input type="number" name="num3"></p>
<p>Enter number 4:<input type="number" name="num4"></p>
<p>Enter number 5:<input type="number" name="num5"></p>
<p>Position:<input type="number" name="pos"></p>
<button type="submit" onclick="findthenum()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Note that we are counting starting from 0, as arrays indexes.

Comment: Thank you sir! But can you help me because in this code. When finding the second lowest number. When i  change the inside of the array. It shows zero

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you be more specific?