# How array of 2 has length 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays

As it's common arrays in js if you put 3 elements in array it will has length 3 but if I make array with only number two, it has length 2 ?!

```
const myArry=new Array(2)
console.log(myArry.length) // 2
```

Comment: Array(2) will create an array like [undefined,undefined] and therefore is length 2

Comment: because it's a constructor for an array and if it contains a single positive integer, it generates an array of this length.

Comment: If the argument to `new Array()` is a single integer, it's the length of the array to create, not a value to put into the array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the way of declaring an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403068/what-is-the-way-of-declaring-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Array(2)` means "make me an array with two empty slots". So yes, it has length 2.

You may be looking for `const myArry = [2]` which has length 1.

EDIT

Just for fun, if you really wanted to use constructor syntax instead of *array literal* syntax (the `[2]` part), you could do:

```
new Array(1).fill(2)
```

Which actually could make sense if both the length and the fill value were dynamic parameters.