# Why does this simple javascript array fail?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am getting old or just rusty or both, but I hang my head in shame as I bring this here because there must be something really, really simple that I am missing.

I am writing this using Google Apps script in Sheets.

Why does this fail once I reach j = 2? I have tried declaring the array in every different way I can think of, nothing gets past j=2. Wth am I missing? It's something dumb I know it.

```js
function myFailure() {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < 31; k++) {
      var item = 'Item '+k;
      let thisItem = new Array([],[]);
      thisItem[j][k] = item;  //the problem is happening here, once j=2 but why
      console.log(j,k);
      console.log(thisItem[j][k]);
    }
  }
}

myFailure();
```

Comment: `console.log(thisItem)` and I think this will point you out to the solution ;)

Comment: `new Array([], [])` creates an array with 2 arrays in it. When `j` is 0 or 1, it works, but not when it's 2.

Comment: In general it's better to use the `myArray = []` format instead of `new Array()`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11403068) as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFailure() {
  let thisItem = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    thisItem[j] = []
    for (var k = 0; k < 31; k++) {
      thisItem[j][k] = `Item [${j}][${k}]`
      console.log(thisItem[j][k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Partial Execution log

```
10:04:00 AM Info    Item [0][0]
10:04:00 AM Info    Item [0][1]
10:04:00 AM Info    Item [0][2]
10:04:00 AM Info    Item [0][3]
10:04:00 AM Info    Item [0][4]
10:04:00 AM Info    Item [0][5]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see the issue now. I was bunching up my array in the loop.